# How to check the given values are updated are not into Database in php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doing webservice using laravel,Here I need to send response after the value get updated into database...

I tried something like this,

```
public function getPhoneverify(){
    $_REQUEST['user_id']    = str_replace('"','', $_REQUEST['user_id']);
    $_REQUEST['status']     = str_replace('"','', $_REQUEST['status']);

    $user = \DB::table('tb_users')->where('id', $_REQUEST['user_id'] )->update(array('phone_verified' => $_REQUEST['status']));
    if($user)
    {
        echo "success";exit;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "failed";exit;
    }
}
```

But here,always it shows the else part message,even if the value get updated into the database..

How should I do this..

Is there any other option to do this!!..

Someone help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to check if the query was successful, I'd suggest a different approach. Assuming the `user_id` field is unique, following should work:

```
$user = \DB::table('tb_users')->where('id', $_REQUEST['user_id'] )->first();
```

Or you can also retrieve the user like this:

```
$user = \DB::table('tb_users')->find($_REQUEST['user_id']);
```

And then update/save it:

```
$user->fill(array('phone_verified' => $_REQUEST['status']));
$saved = $user->save(); //this will always return true or false.
    if($saved)
    {
        echo "success";exit;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "failed";exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use exception handling if you want

```
try {

    $user = \DB::table('tb_users')->where('id', $_REQUEST['user_id'] )->update(array('phone_verified' => $_REQUEST['status']));

}catch(\Exception $e){
    //write statements here if query fails 
}
```

By the way as far I know **DB::update()** returns **boolean**

Comment: I tried this once But I always shows the success msg..If query error occurs I return that query errors

Comment: then you can use the **save()** method.You can solve it :) :)

Comment: Yes..I did it.. :) Thank you for your reply.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The return value will never be true since it returns the number of rows affected by the database transaction.

So you should check for the integer value,  not if it is true or false

Comment: If you have model you can do this `$user=User::where('id', $_REQUEST['user_id'] )->update(array('phone_verified' => $_REQUEST['status']));`

Comment: @Marko Milivojevic Thank you so much.. :)